# Android canvas Drawable position translation

Tags: android, android-canvas

I Created my custom view in which i placed one drawable, I need to change its position. I have 2 Rectangles(Rect) which have the top, bottom left, right. Now I need to give translation effect by Changing Rect.
Lets suppose Rect1 have top = 100 & Rect2 have top = 200. So I need to do translation from 100 to 200 with anim duration.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: " I need to change its position" position of what? how did you "place" a drawable?

Comment: I draw a drawable using drawable.draw(canvas);

Comment: ok and you want to change its bounds?

Comment: Yeah its bounds but with translation animation.Basically i need to find difference between 2Rect & then animation need to aplly with delay.

Comment: so use ValueAnimator / ObjectAnimator

Comment: Can u provide any link. It will really helpful for me

Comment: see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Comment: I need to put objectAnimator on drawable or on canvas? I suppose it on drawable

Comment: it does not matter, you can set a target to your view or to drawable (if it is your custom Drawable), if it isn't a custom Drawable you cannot use it as a target

Comment: Im using ObjectAnimator like this. But no Animation. ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drawable,
        "x", 50f);
      ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drawable,
        "y", 100f);
      AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
      animSetXY.setDuration(1000);
      animSetXY.playTogether(animX, animY);
      animSetXY.start();